Checking if pcap file is damaged (with tshark or possibly something else)
I have a very specific need regarding pcap files generated by wireshark or similar: I need to test quickly if specific pcap file is damaged. Say, if first 100 packets are written correctly to it.
I have tshark available on hosts where files will be used.
The problem: we're using a lot of pcap files and unfortunately some of them get corrupted for reasons I won't get into. I need to do quick sanity check of a file before it being tcpreplayed. I don't need to eliminate absolute 100% of them, just obviously and grossly corrupted ones.

tcpdump -c N or tshark -c N just reads the first N packets and then stops
